# What does PrintStream flush?

Tags: java

I'm reading Java tutorial and it is written that, for buffered IO, there are classes named Buffered[something]. Am I right then that the classes `PrintStream` and `PrintWriter` are unbuffered. If it is so, then what do they flush?

Comment: Most wrapping `OutputStream`s and `Writer`s delegate `flush` to the underlying stream/writer.

Comment: That being said, [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) optionally buffers.

Comment: I believe PrintWriter is buffered.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad What is the point then in differentiating between buffured and unbuffered (if they all are buffered) IO and giving classes such names.

Answer (score 0):

> A PrintStream adds functionality to another output stream, namely the
>   ability to print representations of various data values conveniently.
>   Two other features are provided as well. Unlike other output streams,
>   a PrintStream never throws an IOException; instead, exceptional
>   situations merely set an internal flag that can be tested via the
>   checkError method. Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to
>   flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically
>   invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is
>   invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written.